# List all routes with group in php slim 3

Tags: php, slim-3

I need to get all routes grouped in an array with child routes in Slim 3.

Here's my code:

```
$routes = $app->getContainer()->router->getRoutes();
$routes_list = [];
foreach ($routes as $index => $route) {
   $routes_list[$index]['name'] = $route->getName();
   $routes_list[$index]['pattern'] = $route->getPattern();
   $routes_list[$index]['callable'] = $route->getCallable();
   $routes_list[$index]['methods'] = $route->getMethods();
}
```

Comment: Please post what you'd like the output structure to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got a solution

my code

```
    $routes = $app->getContainer()->router->getRoutes();

    foreach ($routes as $index => $route) {
        $group = explode('.', $route->getName());
        if (is_array($group) and count($group) > 1) {
            $sub_group = explode('.', $route->getName());
            if (is_array($group) and count($group) > 2) {
                $routes_list[$group[0]][$group[1]][$index]['name'] = $route->getName();
                $routes_list[$group[0]][$group[1]][$index]['pattern'] = $route->getPattern();
                $routes_list[$group[0]][$group[1]][$index]['methods'] = $route->getMethods();
            } else {
                $routes_list[$group[0]][$index]['name'] = $route->getName();
                $routes_list[$group[0]][$index]['pattern'] = $route->getPattern();
                $routes_list[$group[0]][$index]['methods'] = $route->getMethods();
            }
        } else {
            $routes_list['routes'][$index]['name'] = $route->getName();
            $routes_list['routes'][$index]['pattern'] = $route->getPattern();
            $routes_list['routes'][$index]['methods'] = $route->getMethods();
        }
    }
```

> it return routs group with child routs in array like this